# OBS crashes immediately after selecting the screen. It was working fine before today

Tags: screen, obs-studio

I use OBS exclusively to record my screen for some lectures. It was working fine until an auto-update happened yesterday. Now whenever I select my screen to capture, OBS crashes.

```
info: Loaded scenes:
info: - scene 'Scene':
info: - scene 'Vertical Scene':
info:     - source: 'Screen Capture (PipeWire)' (pipewire-desktop-capture-source)
info: ------------------------------------------------
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
info: [obs-websocket 4.9.1-compat] WSServer::start: Not locked to IPv4 bindings
info: [obs-websocket 4.9.1-compat] server started successfully on port 4444
info: [obs-websocket 4.9.1-compat] IO thread started.
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to DeviceWidget "Desktop Audio", which already has a layout
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to DeviceWidget "Mic/Aux", which already has a layout
info: [pipewire] Screencast session created
info: [pipewire] Asking for desktop
info: adding 42 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 42 milliseconds (source: Mic/Aux)

info: [pipewire] desktop selected, setting up screencast
error: bmalloc: Allocating 0 bytes is broken behavior, please fix your code! This will crash in future versions of OBS.
error: bmalloc: Allocating 0 bytes is broken behavior, please fix your code! This will crash in future versions of OBS.
error: bmalloc: Allocating 0 bytes is broken behavior, please fix your code! This will crash in future versions of OBS.
error: bmalloc: Allocating 0 bytes is broken behavior, please fix your code! This will crash in future versions of OBS.
[E] pw.loop [loop.c:86 pw_loop_new()] 0x55a1b8881cc0: can't make support.system handle: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: If you need a screen recording software in the meantime, I recommend "SimpleScreenRecorder" it's in the Ubuntu Software store if you want to try it.

Comment: Same here. OBS Studio only works after installing. If I close it and try to launch it again, I get the segmentation fault error